# Blender interface is looking different

Tags: interface

I recently started in unity and for making models, i went for blender. I was watching tutorial, but the guy was having a totally different interface from mine. I wasnt even able to find some stuff. I am using 2.82. The video is from October 2018. Here is the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFN4F9dmpIQ

Here is my photo:
[image]

I don't know if i have to arrange my panels in a certain way, or it is from the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has an old version with dark skin. Since 2.8 version interface was redesigned and changed.

Comment: Ok. I decided to fiddle around with it and i see that the things are just moved in a different way.